# iOS 15 - Xcode 13-RC warning: -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ios15, xcode13

I installed the new Xcode 13-RC and in my project I got the next warning in the console:

```
2021-09-15 17:30:06.305218+0100 MYProject[511:30187] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x1f6902270) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.keys', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDate' (0x1f68f7640) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "'NSDictionary' (0x1f68f77a8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
```

Does anybody know what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are seeing this as well and have traced it back to the Firebase Crashlytics library. I don't think there's anything we can do except update after they patch it on their end. [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8636).

EDIT: This has been fixed in the latest version of Crashlytics.

Comment: In our project we are also using Crashlytics framework. But I am not sure because that log does not have any “word” about it.

Comment: @EduardoSanti the way I confirmed that it was caused by Crashlytics was by commenting out the lines that set up Crashlytics in my AppDelegate. Then I ran the app and didn't see the logs. Maybe you could do something similar? For me the line I commented out looked like `FirebaseApp.configure()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right MattL! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MattL it is from Firebase because if you search for `NSKeyedUnarchiver` in your workspace/project, you should get results only in Firebase related dependencies.